# Interface binding to the ViewModel without MVVM packages

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to call a service interface in the ViewModel constructor without using any libraries for MVVVM like `MVVMLight` etc like

```
public HomePageViewModel(IHomeService homeService)
{
}
```

This is how we do it using a MVVM light.

```
    IService _tService;
     public HomePageViewModel(IHomeService homeService, INavigationServiceExtended navigationService, IService tService)
    {
    _tService=tService;
    }
```

How can I get the send the `IHomeService` instance from the view while binding the View to the ViewModel .

Answer (score 0):

When using DI you either inject the dependency in the calling code, in your case you do something like this:

```
var homePageViewMdel = new HomePageViewModel(new HomeServiceImplementation());
```

Or either you would use an IoC container like (Unity, DryIoc or Autofac) or write your own IoC from scratch.